# Foreign key constraint fails in phpmyadmin while creating foreign key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating foreign key but continuously getting error

> ## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`demo_db`.`#sql-271c_ac`, CONSTRAINT `company_state_id` FOREIGN
>
> KEY (`company_state_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`Id`))

SQL query is

```
 ALTER TABLE `state` ADD CONSTRAINT `company_state_id` FOREIGN KEY (`company_state_id`) REFERENCES `company`(`Id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

[image]

Comment: There are data in your table, that injure the foreign key constraind

Comment: You have to clear all data in your table and you can add constraint

Comment: Any other idea because i have more than 100 records in my table.

Comment: What i did. First I added all records in my table then  i added one more column for foregin key.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE `state` ADD CONSTRAINT `company_state_id` FOREIGN KEY (`company_state_id`) REFERENCES `company`(`Id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

This will first ignore all foreign key checks, alter your table and again restore the check to 1

Hope this helps :)